# fast video overlay on a png image

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay

I am using the following code to overlay my video on a background `.png` file:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\image.png -i C:\input.mp4  \
-filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=-1:950[ovrl][0v]; \
[0v][ovrl]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=0[watermark]" \
-map "[watermark]" -map 1:a -codec:v libx264 -preset veryfast \
-crf 18 -c:a copy C:\output.mp4
```

So, basically, my image.png is 1800x1200 and I am overlaying the video on top of this image starting from `y=0` and the `x` coordinate to fall into the middle of the image. 
However, since my input videos are of different resolution, of different sizes, that is why I am scaling the videos to fit exactly a height of `950 pixels` and of a relative width. 
Everything is working fine!
**The question is: how can I optimize this process to get the same result but MUCH FASTER?** 
This is taking ages to process the videos one by one.

### output

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please show the complete console output from your command.

Comment: Why are you using scale2ref with a fixed resolution? The whole idea of using scale2ref is that the reference is unknown or varying in size. For a fixed height of 950, you can just use regular scale and save some time.

Comment: @Mulvya how? can you give an example?

Comment: Replace with `"[1:v]scale=-1:950[ovrl];[0:v][ovrl]overlay=.....`

Comment: @Mulvya your suggestion doesn't make the process faster, but it changes the scaling system. Mine rescaled everything to a a height of 950px and the width accordingly and leaving me the same margin of the background image. but yours, doesn't leave the same margins, the margins get reduced, I see less of the background image.

Comment: That's because your image has ratio 3:2 and video 16:9. With scale2ref, the video is being *distorted* to 3:2. The regular scale filter preserves the video's original ratio.

Comment: @Mulvya as i stated in the question, my image size and ratio is the same but the video size/codec/resolution/ratio is different from one video to another. I am trying to batch process everything (more than 10000 videos) so I need to find the fastest way to put this background image behind the videos, so as to center the video on the background image.

Comment: What I'm saying is that using your present command (scale2ref) will distort videos whose ratio is different than the image. For speeding up, try `-profile:v baseline`

Comment: @Mulvya so what will be the final version of the command be like according to your suggestion

Comment: What I mentioned above. + `-profile:v baseline`. Don't expect this to go *much* faster.

Comment: Please copy and paste the text instead of making images of text. You will probably see a speed increase using the `ultrafast` preset instead of `veryfast`.